# AmazonAuroraMySQLの「SELECT * INTO OUTFILE S3」で「FORMAT{ CSV|TEXT} [HEADER]」オプションが使用できない

Tags: mysql, aws, sql, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

#### 環境

- AuroraMySQL 5.6.10a (provisioned)
- ap-northeast-1

**動作OK**

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] INTO OUTFILE S3 's3uri' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

は正常に実行されますが、オプション FORMAT{ CSV|TEXT} [HEADER]を追加すると動作しません。

**動作NG**

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] INTO OUTFILE S3 's3uri' 
FORMAT CSV HEADER
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

**エラーコード**

```
SQL :#42000 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FORMAT CSV HEADER FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES '
```

[Amazon Aurora MySQL DBクラスターのデータをAmazon S3バケットのテキストファイルに保存する](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.SaveIntoS3.html)で、このオプションが使用できる事が記述されています。またAuroraMySQLのバージョンによる制限等は見つかりませんでした。  
正常に動作しない理由がわかる方いらっしゃいますでしょうか？

Comment: 該当するのか不明ですが、この記事[Amazon Aurora MySQLとS3間でデータをロード&アンロードする](https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/aurora-mysql-integrate-with-s3/)の説明[Aurora のデータを S3 に保存](https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/aurora-mysql-integrate-with-s3/#toc-12)にはFORMATオプションが無いので、そういう環境または版数が存在するのかもしれません。

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。とりあえず現状のAuroraMySQL5.6.10aでは使えなそうですね。他のAuroraMySQLのバージョンを試せる機会があれば検証してみたいと思います。